# Can I run virtualbox 64bit OS in a Azure Virtual Machine?

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, azure

I installed VirtualBox 4.3.2 in my Azure Virtual Machine, but I can't open a 64 bit VM (Windows Server 2012 R2 64bit).

Virtualbox send a message about not having vt-x support

Can I configure my Azure VM somehow?

Comment: Azure is already a virtual machine! What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to do nested virtualization?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Using a VirtualBox VM because a previous machine have a lot of configuration that I don't want to reconfigure ...

Comment: @joeqwerty yep, just trying to run a previous Virtualbox VM in Azure

Comment: What OS is your VM? I think you'd be better off finding a way to migrate it.

Comment: This is why we have things like ansible, chef, salt, puppet...

Comment: @john Windws Server 2012 R2 both, the host and the guest OS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a few exceptions, such as classic VMware on the guest, it's not possible to nest virtualization within virtualization.  Although this would be a convenience for you, you'll have to attack it from another angle.  Perhaps look into exporting a machine image from Virtualbox and then importing to Azure.

However, I did find somebody doing just what you ask:
https://therightjoin.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/run-virtualbox-on-an-azure-virtual-machine/

This may work for 32-bit versions of guests, since those version do not require the hardware virtualization to be enabled (VT-d).  I doubt you'll have any success with 64-bit guests.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can technically run a 64-bit guest OS now as long as VT-d is enabled, via Hyper-V or VirtualBox. The bigger question is if the Azure physical servers have this enabled (perhaps a specific region?). I tried this on a Windows 10 64-bit VM which shows VT-d is not available. So, on the south-central region, this still doesn't seem possible unless MS changes the bios on their host machines.

Answer (score 2):

For those like me, landing here from a search, this has changed: you can do nested virtualization with the new Dv3/Ev3 VMs: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/

Comment: Just a heads up to anyone looking at this. This still won't work with VirtualBox. Hyper-V nested virtualization is fine though

Comment: I was able to install VirtualBox on Ev3 VM and deploy a VM there. It runs very slow (comparing to Hyper-V nested VM), but still - it runs nowadays

Comment: Also worked for me with both virtualbox and vmware player.